# Properties of eigenpairs of Sturm-Liouville Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove the following and am struggling.  I've tried to prove this in a similar method as done in proving this for matrices, but don't believe this is correct.  Help is appreciated, as this is a fact that is used in a proof of a theorem, but I don't yet believe that it is true.

Prove that if $\lambda_0$, $x_0$ is an eigenpair for the Sturm Liouville Problem (SLP), then $\overline{\lambda_0}, \overline{x_0}$ is also an eigenpair.

Here the SLP is defined as follows
$$Lx=-\lambda r(t)x$$
$$\alpha x(a)-\beta x^{\prime}(a)=0$$
$$\gamma x(b)+\delta x^{\prime}(b)=0.$$

Here $r(t)$ is a weight function, and $\alpha ,\beta, \gamma, \delta$ are constants such that
$$\alpha^2+\beta^2>0$$
$$\gamma^2+\delta^2>0$$

Comment: I'm assuming that the coefficients of the differential operator $L$ are real, and that $\alpha, \beta,\gamma\,\delta$ are real constants, too. Then all you have to do is conjugate all of the equations and see what $\overline{x_{0}}$ satisfies.

Comment: So you just use the fact that you are taking conjugates of all fo the terms and the real terms have themself as a conjugate so we end up having $L\overline{x_0}=\overline{\lambda_0}\overline{x_0}$?

Comment: Yes, and $\overline{x_{0}}$ satisfies the same endpoint conditions as $x_{0}$ because $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are real.